# Is it possible to change terminal's prompt in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I use `docker exec -it container_name bash` to connect to a container, I see this prompt:

```
root@79b47570f92f:/#
```

Can I tell docker to change it to `root@database:/#`? How?

Comment: Remember that any work you do in an interactive shell like this will be lost as soon as the container exits.  `docker exec` is definitely useful, but I wouldn't expect it to be the way you normally work with a container, and I wouldn't invest time in (non-programming) tasks like customizing the shell prompt.

Comment: @DavidMaze, using `docker-compose` we could use `hosename: something` property and it won't be lost. And that's exactly how we do work with a container. We use `docker exec bash` to get an interactive terminal to execute commands. Is there any other options to work with a container?

Comment: You'd typically work with a network interface to the process running inside a container, like using `curl` or a browser to talk to its HTTP interface.

Comment: @DavidMaze, of course we do that. We run our APIs inside container and we use REST clients or GraphQL to talk to it. But once in a while we need to sit behind the container and run some OS-level commands in it. That's why we use `docker exec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is the hostname. You can change it by changing hostname. One way to change it is to specify hostname with `-h` flag when running the container:

```
docker run -h database -ti your_container_image bash
```

Comment: can I change it in docker-compose too?

Comment: @Bigboy looks like you can as of docker-compose version 3: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Answer (score 0):

I am running the container as `--network host` and it's sometimes difficult to see if I'm on the host? or in the container? when they share the exact same prompt. A prompt customization  `-h my-database` in this case is a big win!!

```
docker run -it --network host -h my-database my-container:local /bin/bash
```

Comment: You are saying thanks for a solution you found here, aren't you? If your post is meant to provide an answer according to [answer] you will have to [edit] in order to make that more obvious.

Comment: I want to add to the previous answer and say thanks :)

Comment: Then please [edit] to make much more obvious which additional insight you contribute beyond the post you are thanking for. Also (because at least theoretically this page might not stay on two answers) please use a link to refer to the answer you are building on. Make sure that what you are adding to the answer is actually extending the answer to the question at the top of this page (and not e.g. answering your own different question). Also make sure that you avoid the "thanks only" impression I got, i.e. "linked answer will help me with my problem, thanks". Move the thanks to comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34416962)